# WPF : Binding error for datatable and datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatable, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to bind a datatable to the datagrid. I am having this strange issue where all the string columns are being displayed along with data but for numeric columns (double data type) only column header is being created and all the cells are blank.

[image]

This is the binding error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: '11'
>   property not found on 'object' ''DataRowView' (HashCode=9109783)'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=11/7/2018; DataItem='DataRowView'
>   (HashCode=9109783); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target
>   property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Code for datacontext:

```
public MainWindow()
 {
   InitializeComponent();
   TestModel testModel = new TestModel();
   this.DataContext = testModel;
 }



 public class TestModel
    {
        public DataView TestTableView { get; set; }

        public TestModel()
        {
            TestTableView = GetData().DefaultView;
        }
........
```

XAML

```
 <DataGrid
            x:Name="DgTest"
            Margin="5"
            FontFamily="Tahoma"
            AutoGenerateColumns="True"
            CanUserAddRows="False"
            HorizontalGridLinesBrush="LightGray"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding TestTableView}" />
    </Grid>
```

Data is available in the datatable for all columns. I can evn  export the data table to Excel and there's nothing missing. Only in the Datagrid, its comes up as blank.

Any idea/solution why this is happening?

Comment: Are you able to change to column names? It looks like the slashes might be causing the issue.

Comment: @NeilB, you got it right. I was just testing, after posting the question, its the date format which is screwing up with datagrid. Apparently dd-MM-yyyy is the only format that's working. I have changed that in my datatable and now its all good.